# how achive numeric value search in full text search?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

**like condition :**

```
product.product_name like '%7 up%'
```

**output [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5F8a0.png)**

fulltext search :

```
MATCH(product.product_name) AGAINST('+7+up' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

or

```
MATCH(product.product_name) AGAINST('"7 up"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

How come above both queries are not returning any result ?

Comment: That doesn't look like a numeric search to me.

Comment: first numeric then it's letter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First expression looks good, however you should be aware that, by default, MySQL ignores words shorter than three characters. This is controlled by parameter [innodb_ft_min_token_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_min_token_size). It is possible to change that parameter but it requires to restart the server and rebuild your FULLTEXT indexes ; this is not recommended by mysql. See [this document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html) for more details on Fulltext tuning.

Second expression, with enclosing double quotes, will try to perform a *litteral match* : this does not seem to be what you need.

To make it short : given what you are searching for, you are probably better off using `LIKE`.

Comment: not working with this query MATCH(product.product_name) AGAINST('+7 +up' IN BOOLEAN MODE) it's giving no result found if i'm try with this like condition product.product_name like '%7 up%' it's giving result

Comment: @jayaprakashk : I changed my answer, please check